# Angular service with ES6 class and Babel

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-services

I'm trying to use an ES6 class as an Angular service but when it's instantiated, the methods do not have access to the constructor variables.

```
class dataWrapperService {

    constructor($q, $log) {
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$log = $log;
    }

    data() {
        console.log(this.$q);
    }
}

dataWrapperService.$inject = ['$q', '$log'];

app.service('dataWrapper', dataWrapperService);
```

Once the service gets injected by Angular and I call the data method on it, the method fails to have access to the constructor values.

```
// calling the data method results in an error
dataWrapper.data();   //TypeError: Cannot read property '$q' of undefined

//  console.log output of dataWrapper:
Object
  $log: Object
  $q: Q(resolver)
  __proto__: smDataWrapperService
    constructor: smDataWrapperService($q, $log)
    data: data()
    __proto__: Object
```

BUT...

I can **new** the dataWrapperService manually and that works just fine.

```
var dataWrapper = new smDataWrapperService("hello", "sir");
dataWrapper.data();   // "hello"
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

---

This seems to be happening only in promise callbacks:

I usually pass functions to **then / catch** like this:

```
$http.get('whatever').then(dataWrapper.data);
```

But only the following will work:

```
$http.get('whatever').then((response) => smDataWrapper.data(response))
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular needs a function at `app.factory('dataWrapper', dataWrapperService);` and not a class.

You could add a static factory method to your class and add that to `app.factory`.
(see update below code snippet)

The code like this should work:

```
class dataWrapperService {

    constructor($q, $log) {
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$log = $log;
    }

    data() {
        console.log(this.$q);
    }

    static dataWrapperFactory($q, $log) {
        dataWrapperService.instance = new dataWrapperService($q, $log);
        return dataWrapperService.instance;
    }
}

dataWrapperService.$inject = ['$q', '$log'];

app.factory('dataWrapper', dataWrapperService.dataWrapperFactory);
```

**Update**

So as mentioned in the comments your code should work because an ES6 class  is a constructor function and that's what `angular.service` is expecting.

I'll check later if I can see any other issue with your code.

Comment: I thought that angular.service took a constructor function and called "new" on it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. My code is for a factory. I'll correct that. I don't know what's wrong with your code. I've seen many examples that did it like in your code.

Comment: It seems that this only happens with promises. Updated the examples above.

Comment: This is not safe and won't survive js minify

Answer (score 2):

*I know this is late, but maybe somebody will stumble upon this issue like me today with similar problems, so...*

Actually, it's not about promises. When you do this:

```
let function1 = () => {}
let function2 = function1
```

actually, `this` object is different for the functions. Therefore, when you try `.then(function1)`, actually `function1` is being copied to the param `successCallback` and it's `this` is changed.

But when you use `.then(() => function1())`, `successCallback` receives your lambda, and the actual `this` of `function1` is not lost.

So if you do not know, what you do **never** assign a function to a function in javascript, use lambdas instead

Comment: If you want to assign a service class' method to a controller function, do it like `$scope.isLoggedIn = () => { Auth.isLoggedIn(); };`, instead of `$scope.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;`. Otherwise the `this` will be pointing to the controller itself, and not to the class. Thx for the eye-opener.

Comment: @arcol I've spent several hours some time ago trying to figure that out, glad I can spare somebody this pain

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 1.6.4, I'm getting the error when I'm trying to inject a service that is defined as a class in some controller.

> Cannot call a class as a function

So instead, I want to use a function as a service. To keep it as clean as possible I would export a function that immediately returns an instantiated anonymous class. And do this in a separate file and import and use that function to create the service in another file.

And since you're asking to use ES6 with Babel, use the [babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate](https://github.com/schmod/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate) to safely inject dependencies by adding `'/* @ngInject */'` above the exported function.

The injected services `$q` and `$log` or available to the class by closure. (No need to pass them in the constructor and assign to this.)

```
// dataWrapperService.js
/* @ngInject */
export const dataWrapperService = ($q, $log) => new class {
  constructor() {
    // do stuff
  }

  data() {
    // $q available through closure
    console.log($q)
  }
}()

// in your.module.js
import angular from 'angular'

import { dataWrapperService } from './dataWrapperService'

export const YourModule = angular
  .module('yourmodule', [])
  .factory('dataWrapper', dataWrapperService)
  .name
```